# Why aren't events overridden in the same way properties are?

Tags: c#, events, overriding

This does not refer to any actual code, it's just curiosity...

I was playing with some C# and came across this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        protected bool boolean;
        public virtual bool Boolean { get { return boolean; } set { boolean = value; Console.WriteLine("AB"); } }

        public virtual event Action action;

        public A()
        {
            action += () => Console.WriteLine("AA");
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public override bool Boolean { get { return boolean; } set { boolean = value; Console.WriteLine("BB"); } }

        public override event Action action;

        public B() : base()
        {
            action += () => Console.WriteLine("BA");
        }

        public void Invoke()
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();

        b.Boolean = false;
        b.Invoke();
    }
}
```

The written lines are:

```
BB
AA
BA
```

I was expecting only BB and BA would show up...

How come events are treated in a different manner when overridden?

As events are just properties of a delegate type and 'add' / 'remove' seem to work just like any other accessor, I was expecting them to be overridden just like 'get' / 'set' from a regular property.

Comment: Could you please clarify how that is different if you use `public virtual string action {get;set;};` and correspondingly use `action += "AA"` and `action += "BA"`? Or other way - what exactly you expect base class to do when it accesses virtual property/event?

Comment: How is the method they're treated in different? You have a single event object, and you're registering multiple subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

The event dispatchers can have more than one delegate attached to them.

The `action` variable is set in the constructor of `B` which calls the constructor for the base class `A`, note the **: base in**  `public B() : base()`; thus adding a second handler giving the output "AA".